# C getline continuing to take input after newline

Tags: c, gcc, getline

I am trying to essentially take in a line of text from the user, and reverse it.

```
#define LENGTH 0xFF

char *buffer = malloc(LENGTH), *output = malloc(LENGTH);
unsigned char length_read, count = 0;
length_read = getline(&buffer, 0, stdin);

while (length_read >= 0)
  output[count++] = buffer[length_read--];
```

In theory, the value of `output` should be the reverse of `buffer`. But when I run my program, `getline` seemingly doesn't stop reading input from the keyboard and the program doesn't advance. I'm using gcc with `-std=c11`. Out of curiosity, I put two different calls to `printf` on either side of the line calling `getline`, and both printed their outputs. I'm not really sure I'm what I'm doing wrong or misinterpreting.

Comment: Can you check return value of `getline` and get the `length_read` from the function instead of hold return value

Comment: @ThiruShetty I added `printf("%s %d\n", buffer, length_read)` after the `getline` call, and it printed " 255" BEFORE prompting me for input.

Comment: What makes you think you can pass a null pointer for the length?  The POSIX specification for [`getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html) certainly does not allow it — it requires that the function can write to `*n`.  I see no relief in the Linux man pages for [`getline(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) either. I think you're using undefined behaviour; I'm surprised you aren't simply crashing.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler that fixed it, I set a `const` variable to `LENGTH` and passed a reference to that, now everything works properly. If you turn that into an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: If both your `printf()` statements print, then `getline()` itself isn't stuck.  Using `unsigned char` for the return value from `getline()` is dicing with death — it returns a `ssize_t` which is usually at least 4 bytes and oftern 8 bytes long.  You may be misunderstanding what it returns, especially if it encounters EOF and returns `-1` (which is its return value, not EOF, though the two are usually the same).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code, you have:

```
char *buffer = malloc(LENGTH);
unsigned char length_read;
length_read = getline(&buffer, 0, stdin);
```

What makes you think you can pass a null pointer for the length?  The POSIX specification for [`getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html) certainly does not allow it — it requires that the function can write to `*n`.  I see no relief in the Linux man pages for [`getline(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) either. I think you're using undefined behaviour; I'm surprised you aren't simply crashing.

Additionally, if both your `printf()` statements print, then `getline()` itself isn't stuck.

Using `unsigned char` for the return value from `getline()` is dicing with death — it returns a `ssize_t` which is usually at least 4 bytes and often 8 bytes long.  You may be misunderstanding what it returns, especially if it encounters EOF and returns `-1` (and `-1` is its return value when it encounters EOF, not `EOF`, though the two are usually the same).

A more typical use would be:

```
char *buffer = 0;
size_t buflen = 0;

ssize_t length_read = getline(&buffer, &buflen, stdin);
```

Don't forget to free `buffer` even if the input fails; memory may have been allocated even if it immediately gets EOF.